# Wordpress. Можно ли программно определить, что сайт расположен на локальном компьютере (например, на Denwer'e или Open Server'е)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**Общая информация**: я разрабатываю плагин для Wordpress. В нем нужно слать запросы. И на реальных сайтах они отправляются, а на локальном компьютере нужно отправлять их в обход CORS.

**В связи с этим появился вопрос**: возможно ли программно определить, что сайт расположен на локальном компьютере (например, на Denwer'e или Open Server'е), чтобы включать костыль обхода CORS на локальных компьютерах, а на реальных сайтах его отключать? И насколько это безопасно?

Сам механизм обхода CORS на локальном компьютере, если необходим:

```php
// Файл "proxy.php" для проксирования запроса
<?php
$api_url = 'https://ВЕБСАЙТ.РУ';
$headers = array('X-Auth-Key: КОНФИДЕНЦИАЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ КЛЮЧА API');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

```js
// Файл "script.js" для вызова запроса
const url = 'proxy.php'
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text()) // получение текстового ответа
  .then((data) => JSON.parse(data))
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

Comment: А может из js скрипта просто посмотреть на каком url он сейчас работает, если на локальном то там наверное localhost ....

Comment: @Mike, я не вижу никакой информации о **localhost** в **js**: `console.log(window.location)`. 
Ответ в консоли: https://imgur.com/a/TXboUQ2

Comment: В любом случае надо отталкиваться от того, из за чего срабатывают CORS, а они срабатывают если домен ajax запроса отличается от текущего домена сайта и если тот сайт который вызывают отказывается принимать запрос. Это значит что надо проверять текущий домен на несоответствие тому, который ожидает получать вызываемый через ajax сайт